# Creating a generator expression or list comprehension without variable "x in" (e.g. for range) in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, generator-expression

In Python, is there any way to write this list comprehension without the "x in" variable (since it is left completely unused)? Same applies to a generator expression. I doubt this comes up very often, but I stumbled onto this a few times and was curious to know.

Here's an example:

```
week_array = ['']*7
four_weeks = [week_array[:] for x in range(4)]
```

(Also perhaps, is there a more elegant way to build this?)

Comment: @phg: That will result in 4 references to the same list.

Comment: @Ignacio Oh, right... I use to forget that, thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't believe so, and there is no harm in the `x`.  A common thing to see when a value is unused in this way is to use an underscore as the free variable, e.g.:

```
[week_array[:] for _ in range(4)]
```

But it's nothing more than a convention to denote that the free variable goes unused.

Answer (score 3):

No. Both constructs *must* have an iterator, even if its value is unused.

Answer (score 1):

```
week_array = ['']*7
four_weeks = map(list, [week_array]*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to other answers, in that I use map, but what I did uses the same function you are using.

```
four_weeks = map(lambda i: week_array[:], range(4))
```

Also, the main advantage compared to using `_` for example is that it could already be used (`_` is used by gettext often) and it changes its value in to the last item in the iterator. See this example:

```
[x for x in range(4)]
assert x == 3, 'x should be equal to 3'
```